# Text on a Curve and Anchor Points

Tags: adobe-photoshop, path, typesetting

Sorry, i'm sure this is a basic question. I'm trying to create type on a path. It's currently in a S shape. I want to delete the anchor point in the middle so it's simply an arch. but when i delete the middle anchor point, my text disappears. It's showing it's there in my layers panel, but it's not on the path any longer. where did it go and how do i find it? Thanks. Janice

Comment: Try making the path longer so the word can fit on the shape.

Answer (score 1):

If the path is too short, maybe the text has been wrapped onto the next line.

For example, in the next image there are two shapes with the same text, but the first one is shorter than the second one. The word "TooLooooooong" has been wrapped.

[image]